# When using "find" on relation it gives me the pivot id

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Organization model and when i try to retrieve a specific user from this organization it gives me the user, but the ID on the user object is the pivot-id from the many-to-many relation table.

```
class Organization extends Eloquent
{
     public function users()
     { 
          return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'organizations_users', "organization_id" ,"user_id");
     }
}
```

And a user model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    use RemindableTrait;


    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $hidden = array('password');


    protected $fillable = array('email', 'password');

    public function organizations()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Organization', 'organizations_users');
    }

}
```

But when i retrieve a specific organizations users with this method

```
$org = Organization::find(12);
$org->users()->find(4);
```

It returns the pivot-table id on the user-object instead of the users own id.

```
  "id" => 74
    "first_name" => "Thomas"
    "last_name" => "Bolander"
    ....
    "organization_id" => 12
    "user_id" => 4
    ....
```

This works

```
$org = Organization::find(12);
$org->users()->where("users.id",4)->first();
```

Anybody have an idea whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Thomas you can try this too

```
$org->users()->getRelated()->find(4);
```

https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_getRelated

Comment: Hi'!

Thansk for your reply. I think it works, but it should't be necessary to do it that way. :s